# Bootstrap for a print design (not printable)?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I need to build a new website, which is the replicate of an old website. The old website stays the same (no layout/content movement) when a browser window shrinks and grows. The old website also looks the same on all devices, but simply looks a lot smaller on a smartphone.

I need to build the new website and have to make it behave just like the old one. I want to use the Bootstrap framework for the new website. I understand Bootstrap is a great tool for building mobile-friendly websites. But I am not sure  whether it is a good choice or there are any benefits of using Bootstrap in my situation.

If Bootstrap (v3) is a good choice for the project, what to use (or not use) in my situation?

Thanks and regards.

Comment: You want to build a new website that looks and behaves exactly like the old one..... So why are you making a new website?

Comment: The old website was built with old technologies, and has bugs. The customer wants to migrate out of it. I don't make decisions. Thanks for chiming!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Honestly, Bootstrap specializes in helping you create responsive websites, which is not what it sounds like you want. However if you insist on using it:

- Remove `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">` from the `<head>`.
- Don't use any grid elements that you use to make responsive layouts.

Comment: do you happen to know any good CSS framework for my situation?

Comment: Bootstrap is still fine for this, if you don't use the responsive elements of it.